# Use Java Streams to assemble a list

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, collections, java-stream

I have an entity called "File" with the following attributes:

```
public class File {
    private int id;
    private String proposal;
    private String hash;
    private String path;
    private LocalDateTime createdAt;
    private LocalDateTime finishedAt;
    private int size;
    private boolean processed;
}
```

I need to organize a queue of which files will be uploaded to a particular service. For each submission, I can send as many files as possible, as long as the sum of their sizes does not exceed 100mb. Furthermore, I must respect the maximum date allowed for each file (which in this case concerns the finishedAt attribute).

I've already managed to sort my list. In other words, I was able to determine which files will be uploaded first:

```
files.sort(Comparator.comparing(File::getFinishedAt));
files.stream().forEach(file -> System.out.println(file.getId()));
```

Now I would like to assemble an array with lists of which files will be sorted on each submission. Something like that:

```
[[1, 4, 7], [8, 2], [6, 3], [5]]
```

Each "subset" of the above array concerns an upload. And on it are the IDs of my files. So what I would like is for my program to return an array of arrays, where each of the sets contain the largest possible number of files (as long as their sum does not exceed 100mb). As each record has a deadline (finishedAt), they need to be in order as well.

What is the most appropriate way to do this? I'm trying to understand Streams in Java, but the most I could do was sort the list according to date. With the use of Streams I can achieve the result I showed? What is the most appropriate approach to achieve these goals?

Thank you very much!

Comment: It is not clear what you want to do.  Is `[[1, 4, 7], [8, 2], [6, 3], [5]]` of type `File[][]` (or `List<List<File>>`)?  Is that a result of your program, or an input to your program?  What do the individual groups (like `1, 4, 7`) represent?  What does “respecting the maximum date for submission” mean?  Some example inputs and their corresponding output might clarify your goal.

Comment: Oh. I really haven't made these issues clear enough, @VGR. I'll edit my question, but the array is a processing response that shows me the ID of the files that must be uploaded in each batch. In other words: from a list containing all registered files, my program must set up the upload order. Each upload can have multiple files, but they cannot be more than 100mb in total. In addition, each file has a maximum date to be uploaded. My intention is to determine which files will be sent in each batch respecting these requirements (finishedAt and size).

Comment: In my opinion (hence not an official answer), what you want to do is not a good use case for streams. The part that you have so far is fine, but I would write the chunking part as a loop over the list that you currently have, building lists until they are "full", and then adding each of those to the "list of lists".

Even if you do get this working with streams, it's likely that the code won't be very easy to understand, causing a maintenance headache.

Comment: I think you're right, @GreyBeardedGeek  The point is that I'm not very fluent in Java, so I think everything should be done in the "Java 8" way. I'll see if I can get a little closer to the solution taking what you said into account. If it's not asking too much, can you give me an example or pass me some content where I can create this array of arrays?

Comment: Is it guaranteed that the size of each file is below 100 MB?  Otherwise, the file may need to be split additionally to fit into the size limitation.

Comment: Good question, @AlexRudenko . Certainly each file will be less than 100 MB. My program won't upload: it will determine which files should be uploaded in each batch. The response from my program (the array of arrays, in this case) will be sent to another service that will be in charge of doing the size checks.

Comment: By the way, you’ll want `Instant` rather than `LocalDateTime` to represent a moment, a point  on the timeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stream API has its own limitations and may not be applicable well for stateful  operations which occur in the given task: here the sublists should be collected (or appropriate index needs to be incremented) until the size limitation is met, and *then* the calculation should be computed from the last processed index.  That is, there are two state parameters: a total sum and the pair of first/last indexes to define a sublist.

So, good old loop-based solution may be suggested.

**Update**

Added returning of `int[][]` array with the ids.

```java
static int[][] groupFiles(List<File> files) {
    files.sort(Comparator.comparing(File::getFinishedAt));
    
    List<int[]> result = new ArrayList<>();
    
    for (int i = 0, n = files.size(); i < n; i++) {
        int sum = 0;
        int j = i;
        for (; j < n && sum + files.get(j).size <= 100; sum += files.get(j++).size);
    
        System.out.println("total size=" + sum + "; sublist: [" + i + ", " + j + "]");
        
        List<File> sublist = files.subList(i, j);
        
        sublist.forEach(s -> System.out.println("\t" + s));
        i = --j;
        
        sendFiles(sublist);
        result.add(sublist.stream().mapToInt(File::getId).toArray());
    }
    return result.toArray(new int[0][]);
}
```

Test:

```
List<File> files = Arrays.asList(
    new File(1, "f1", LocalDateTime.of(2021, 12, 20, 20, 00), 55),
    new File(2, "f2", LocalDateTime.of(2021, 12, 20, 19, 45), 20),
    new File(3, "f3", LocalDateTime.of(2021, 12, 20, 19, 30), 40),
    new File(4, "f4", LocalDateTime.of(2021, 12, 20, 19, 50), 45),
    new File(5, "f5", LocalDateTime.of(2021, 12, 20, 20, 10), 35)
);
        
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(groupFiles(files)));
```

Output:

```
total size=60; sublist: [0, 2]
    File: id=3; path=f3; finishedAt=2021-12-20T19:30; size=40
    File: id=2; path=f2; finishedAt=2021-12-20T19:45; size=20
total size=100; sublist: [2, 4]
    File: id=4; path=f4; finishedAt=2021-12-20T19:50; size=45
    File: id=1; path=f1; finishedAt=2021-12-20T20:00; size=55
total size=35; sublist: [4, 5]
    File: id=5; path=f5; finishedAt=2021-12-20T20:10; size=35
[[3, 2], [4, 1], [5]]
```

Comment: OMG! I've been racking my brain for days trying to make this selection! Thank you very much!!!

Now I'm going to move on to trying to capture the "id" to return that format I mentioned in my question (an array of arrays, in this case). So, without wanting to abuse it too much (since you helped me immensely), can you just give me a direction on this?

Comment: @SpammingOff, you may check the update

Comment: Thank you very much!!! You helped me a lot with this solution! I was trying out much more complex paths (and not at all elegant). I'm going to go through it line by line to really learn. I'm sure I'll need to develop similar things in the future, and your help was crucial. Thank you so much again!